# How to import attributes using Dataflow advanced profile

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to import attributes and its value using Advanced Profile Dataflow. But I am not able to understand which model or function I need to override. So anybody have idea about which file or method is using for save attributes??

Comment: if you have the value in CSV then write a script, read the CSV and save those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::save() and Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveRow() methods. You will most likely have to extend the class and add your functionality to one of them.

Also, make sure you export one full product to verify if the attribute(s) you are trying to import is not already there and you are using a wrong column header (attribute name).

Comment: But I think this method is used for import products right?

Comment: I need to import attributes and its value only not products.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to create new attributes while importing Products. That's the only way I have done it so far. I won't be of much help then.